# Spring Boot: Hibernate doesn't use application.properties configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am building a Spring-Boot 2.3.1 application which uses a file-based HSQL database for testing. `application.properties` contains the following database configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/db/trainingdata
spring.datasource.username=sa 
spring.datasource.password=
```

However, Hibernate doesn't seem to pick up any of this. I can completele delete or invalidate each line without effect. Following a log excerpt:

```
....mmr.ApplicationTest            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 94ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
hsqldb.db.HSQLDB6A89996F0E.ENGINE        : checkpointClose start
hsqldb.db.HSQLDB6A89996F0E.ENGINE        : checkpointClose synched
hsqldb.db.HSQLDB6A89996F0E.ENGINE        : checkpointClose script done
hsqldb.db.HSQLDB6A89996F0E.ENGINE        : checkpointClose end
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
....mmr.ApplicationTest            : Started ApplicationTest in 4.133 seconds (JVM running for 5.115)
o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

`application.properties` values **are** getting used for other things, so the file works in general. Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: where is your application.properties file located? Locating it in the resources folder may do the trick.

Comment: what exactly makes you think hibernate is not using this datasoruce?

Comment: `application.properties` is located in src/test/resources an gets picked up for other configuration. First, I can change `spring.datasource.url` to any nonsense and nothing changes. Second, queries against it are always empty while there are acutally entries. Further, I can see that hibernate creates the table (probably in memory mode) when sql logging is active.

Comment: can you change the location of the file  to src/main/resources and check if there's any change?